# IOS Post Request using Multiple Images

Tags: ios, post, base64, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

Below is my code for sending a post request consisting of 4 base64Image data to my server.

```
NSString *postURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&mobile=%@&email=%@&bday=%@&image=%@&img1=%@&img2=%@&img3=%@",@"abin",@123",@"abc@gmail.com",@"01-01-1990",[base64Value]image,[base64 value] of img1,[base64 value] of img2,[base64 value] of img3"];

NSData *postData = [postURL dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

**Here all the image values img1,image,image are base64 values.**

While sending this request to the server, 6 out of 10 times, it gets failed.

Over Wi-Fi success rate is high and over Mobile Data it is very low.

**Image conversion is done using the below code:**

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSData *imageBase64Data = [data base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
NSString *imageBase64String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageBase64Data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return imageBase64String;
}
```

Any once please help me with some idea to successfully send multiple images to Server using POST request even when the network connectivity is slow.(2G)

Answer (score 0):

in interface:-

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

in viewdidload:

```
 if (!queue) {
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("name", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    }
```

in your method:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            //do the post code here
        });
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           //do the ui update part here
        });

   }
```

Comment: Kedar : Thanks for your reply. But for me my code is working but not always. I don't want to update any UI using the response also.